Teaching material for a one hour refresher on probability theory (conditional probability)
I have been teaching a course on stochastic processes to master students in theoretical physics, and half of my students seem to have never taken a probability course and struggle with some basic concepts such as conditional probability, conditional expected value, and conditional variance. They're physicists, so they have seen a lot of probabilistic calculations in quantum mechanics and statistical physics, they know mean and variance, and have used probability density functions.
I did not want to teach them a basic probability lecture because of time constraints and not wanting to lose more advanced students. I also do not need a formal definition of probability involving measures.
They usually do fine with half of the course, but when I start writing things like
$$
\text{Var}(X) = \left\langle\text{Var}(X|Y) \right\rangle + \text{Var}(\left\langle X|Y\right\rangle),
$$
I lose most of the students.
What I'm looking for: I am looking for a good reference (short book chapter, lecture notes, video lectures + a problem set) to give a one to two-hour lecture on conditional probability, conditional expected value, conditional variance, and some review of maybe more basic stuff. Something that is not too formal (no measure theory, no formal proofs) and is suitable for master students in theoretical physics who have seen some probability but need a refresher on the more advanced stuff.
I know I can write this myself, but it feels like reinventing the wheel, as no doubt, many other lecturers have faced this problem teaching in physics, and by now have perfected the way to do this.
Edit: Looking through the references suggested in the answer and comments, I feel I have to emphasize that the students usually do fine with half of the course until I start writing expressions like the equation above. This is the type of material I need to cover. And something that I can cover in one lecture. I'm looking for something ready to use, otherwise, I would just write it myself.

You mean conditional probability in the discrete case or in the continuous one? Because the second case requires some degree of understanding of measure theory even to grasp the definitions

@Marco, I need both. But this is not a math course, it's a physics course, things don't have to be rigorous. The emphasis is on intuition and being able to calculate things. No proofs

If you would have to re-invent the wheel on conditional expectation with respect to continuous random variables, what definition would you propose that does not involve a Radon-Nikodym derivative?

Not something I know much about, but my initial reaction is to wonder if you've looked over the probability & statistics chapters in the many "mathematics for engineers, physicists, etc." type texts (both undergraduate level and graduate level)? For example, texts by Kenneth S. Miller AND Wilfred Kaplan AND Erwin Kreyszig AND Mary L. Boas are 4 of many such texts. (continued)

Not all will have such a chapter (the 4 I listed do), but many will. Maybe the next time you're at your university library, glance over the books of this type on the library shelves. Maybe also look at the book's probability/statistics chapter's bibliography, if there is one, for specific recommendations by the book's author(s).

Chapter 3: Conditional Probability and Conditional Expectation in Introduction to Probability Models by Sheldon M. Ross. This single chapter has everything you need related to conditional probability and expectation, including intuitions, enough examples, no completely rigorous math. I hope this is helpful!

Thank you for the response. This is a bit on the longer side for a one-hour lecture. But, I'm going through it to see if I can shorten the content. Many thanks!
